# As forças das trevas e da luz são forças...?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Estou tentando encontrar uma palavra que signifique a categoria/grupo à qual as forças da luz e das trevas pertencem.

"Espirituais" ou "místicas" são relacionadas com a área, sendo "espirituais" bem próxima, mas nenhuma das duas é a palavra que eu estou procurando; "metafísicas" ou "transcendentais" dão uma ideia próxima da palavra, mas também não são essas.

Eu lembro que, se eu não estou enganado, existe uma palavra que significa essa ideia na qual estou tentando chegar, que não é nenhuma dessas citadas, mas não lembro qual.

Comment: O que me vem à cabeça é *forças sobrenaturais*. Não sei se é esta a distinção que procuras, natural vs. sobrenatural? Teoricamente, forças naturais poderão incluir forças que não são nem do bem nem do mal. E também é verdade que podemos ter forças do bem ou do mal que são naturais, mas o teu *transcendental* e *místico* parece apontar para o sobrenatural.

Comment: @Jacinto Bom, "sobrenaturais" não é bem a palavra, mas acho que também serve.

Comment: Não sei, talvez se conseguires dizer mais alguma coisa acerca dessa palavra, as conotações que ela tem. Imagino que seja possível incluir forças das trevas e forças da luz em mais do que uma categoria. Já agora, estás a pensar nessas forças nalgum contexto em particular, por exemplo religiões monoteístas, ou uma coisa mais tipo Senhor dos Anéis, outra coisa...

Comment: @Jacinto Então, essa dúvida me veio quando eu estava escrevendo um enredo de ficção fantástica em que há diversos artefatos poderosos, e dentre eles, há dois especiais: um que permite emanar fisicamente e controlar as forças das trevas e outro equivalente para as forças da luz, aí travei quando tentei classificar a categoria em que esses dois especiais fazem parte. Acho que não são espirituais porque o uso desses artefatos não chega a envolver o espírito. Podem até serem sobrenaturais, mas as forças da luz também seriam sobrenaturais?

Comment: @Jacinto o teu primeiro comentário parece uma resposta. :)

Comment: @ANeves Não é, porque não estou seguro de exatamente o que é que o Bruno procura.

Comment: Se são ou não sobrenaturais depende da tua visão das coisas. Por exemplo, em certas visões cristãs da realidade uma pessoa pode ser possuída pelo demónio, e isso é um fenómeno sobrenatural: está para além da natureza e do mundo material. Noutras visão das coisas, uma pessoa ser possuída por outro ser pode ser um fenómeno natural que nós simplesmente não compreendemos. Portanto tu é que tens que decidir qual é a visão das coisas na tua história. O problema é que *forças das trevas e da luz* podem ser coisas diferentes conforme a maneira como uma pessoa entende e imagina a realidade

Comment: @Jacinto Hmm, então acho que "sobrenaturais" seria a mais próxima, mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tuas dicas na pergunta e os esclarecimentos nos comentários sugerem ***sobrenatural, mágico***, ou ***oculto***. Todos estes termos se referem a algo que está para além do mundo material, observável pelos sentidos e explicável pela ciência. Naturalmente que estas categorias são bastante abrangentes: podem incluir coisas que não são forças nem do bem nem do mal. E também podemos classificar entidades naturais como forças do bem ou do mal (Médicos sem Fronteiras, Estado Islâmico, e coisas assim), mas claramente não é a isto que te referes.

Os significados de *sobrenatural, mágico* e *oculto* cruzam-se. Vejamos o que diz o Aulete nas aceções relevantes:

> [**Sobrenatural**](http://www.aulete.com.br/sobrenatural)
>   **1.** Diz-se de fenômeno supostamente extraterreno, que não se tem como comprovar cientificamente (forças sobrenaturais)
>   **2.** Que parece acima dos fatos naturais, fantástico, fora do comum; SOBRE-HUMANO: *Transmitiu-nos uma energia quase sobrenatural.*
>   **3.** Teol. Que só se pode conhecer pela fé
>
> [**Mágico**](http://www.aulete.com.br/m%C3%A1gico)
>   **1.** Ref. a magia ou a mágica
>   **2.** Diz-se de algo que parece não ter explicação racional; MILAGROSO; SOBRENATURAL: *Foi uma cura mágica: os médicos não acreditaram.*
>
> [**Magia**](http://www.aulete.com.br/magia)
>   **1.** Arte, ciência ou prática que supostamente pode produzir fenômenos extraordinários e não naturais, por intermédio de fórmulas e manipulações, seres fantásticos, rituais bizarros etc.; BRUXARIA; FEITIÇARIA: *Recorreu à magia para ter sucesso: Acredita em magia.*
>   […]
>   **5.** Antr. Conjunto de saberes, crenças e práticas, institucionalizados dentro de um grupo social, ref. e inerentes a forças impessoais ou indecifráveis na natureza, na sociedade ou nos indivíduos
>
> [**Oculto**](http://www.aulete.com.br/oculto)
>   **4.** Que é misterioso, sobrenatural (fenômeno oculto): “Não procures nem creias: tudo é oculto” (Fernando Pessoa, “Natal”, *in Cancioneiro*))

Agora, a palavra apropriada e o significado exato dessa palavra depende da visão que se tem da realidade. Na visão da realidade das religiões monoteístas, *sobrenatural* refere-se ao mundo espiritual para além da matéria e não sujeito às leis da física; enquanto *magia* é ou mera crendice ou práticas pelas quais uma pessoa se entrega ao poder do Demónio ou simplesmente se afasta de Deus. Já num visão que à falta de melhor chamarei ‘pagã’, a fronteira entre sujeito e não sujeito às leis da física é muito mais difusa ou mesmo inexistente. E aí magia é mesmo uma forma de manipular a realidade, forma essa que uns dominam e outros não. Curiosamente esta visão ‘pagã’ pode aproximar-se algo das visões da realidade em certa ficção científica, em que não existe sobrenatural: existem fenómenos naturais que nós não compreendemos; e fenómenos naturais que uns compreendem e controlam e outros não.